# EKS: verify connection between ec2 and rds instances and difference between nslookup and telnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

I have setup a RDS instance and I am trying to see if i am able to connect from my EC2 instances(setup using EKS) to the RDS instances.

All my EC2 and RDS instances are in the same VPC.

There is a security group associated with my RDS to which I have set the following inbound and outbound rules.

**Inbound: PostgreSQL 5432 192.168.0.0/32**

**Outbound: All TCP 0-65535 192.168.0.0/32**

I am trying to check if I am able to connect from my ec2 instances to the RDS

when i execute

`kubectl exec -it debug -- telnet xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432` the output is `Connected to xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

but when I execute 
`kubectl exec -it debug -- nslookup xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432` the output is `can't find xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

1. Why does nslookup not work and telnet work?
2. Is telnet a correct way to verify that my EC2 instances will be able to talk to my RDS instances?

Any help on clarifying this would be really great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your questions:

1. Telnet works as the command you used is correct. I believe your nslookup doesn't work because it default to port 53. You could try running it as follows:
   `kubectl exec -it debug -- nslookup -port 5432 xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`
2. Telnet is absolutely right way to verify connectivity, I personally use it all the time to verify connections between my bastion and private RDS or Redis instances.